# How to average non null values with linq / mongodb in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a table with object that have fields tagged with *BsonIgnoreIfDefault*.

When the object is de-serialized, the fields come up as null.

I am trying to make an average over a collection I parse with AsQueryable().

The query looks like this:

```
            var Result = db.Collection.AsQueryable()
                .Where(_ => _.TimeStamp >= From && _.TimeStamp < To)
                .GroupBy(_ => true)  // not sure why, but I can't compile without this
                .Select(_ => new
                    {
                        R = new Result
                        {
                            TimeStamp = From,
                            i = _.Average(P => P.i)
                        },
                        Count = _.Count()
                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```

but sometimes, the *i* field is null. How can I skip the nulls when doing the average this way?

The object is like

```
class A
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp;
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public double i;
}
```

Also, I find that when I deserialize, the object cannot stay null; so I would like to find how to average only the objects that have the property *i*

Comment: Please post the Collection object so we can see what properties are on it.

Comment: `i = _.Where(P => P.i != null).Average(P => P.i)`

Comment: A double cannot be null. Can you please clarify what it is that is null?

Comment: With BsonIgnoreIfDefault, the field can be skipped and some documents do not have the field 'i'. They can't be deserialized because, as you pointed out, null will not become a double. As I'm parsing the collection with AsQueryable, I'd like to be able to skip over the documents where that field is missing to average the ones that have the field.

Comment: So the issue, right now, is that the null values are being treated as `0` and thus lowering the average?

Comment: It's 2 issues: if I let the 0 being written, yes; but if I don't let them be written (with BsonIgnoreIfDefault), I can't even deserialize the document. So I'm trying to find how the document can be checked to see if the field even exists and then be part of the average.

Answer (score -1):

the simple solution is to use a nullable double property `double?`. here's a complete solution that produces the desired result.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Record : Entity
        {
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
            public double? Value { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            (new[] {
                new Record { TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
                new Record { TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow, Value = null },
                new Record { TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow, Value = 2 },
                new Record { TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow, Value = 2 }
            }).Save();

            var from = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1);
            var to = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);

            var result = DB.Queryable<Record>()
                           .Where(r => r.Value != null && r.TimeStamp >= from && r.TimeStamp <= to)
                           .GroupBy(r => true)
                           .Select(g => new
                           {
                               Rec = new Record { TimeStamp = from, Value = g.Average(r => r.Value) },
                               Count = g.Count()
                           })
                           .Single();

            Console.WriteLine($"Average: {result.Rec.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Count: {result.Count}");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

the above is using my library **MongoDB.Entities** but the querying part is the same for `.AsQueryable` of the official driver.

it will produce the following aggregation query:

```java
db.Record.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "Value": {
                "$ne": null
            },
            "TimeStamp": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2019-06-30T07:20:59.126Z"),
                "$lte": ISODate("2019-06-30T07:22:59.126Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": true,
            "__agg0": {
                "$avg": "$Value"
            },
            "__agg1": {
                "$sum": NumberInt("1")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Rec": {
                "TimeStamp": ISODate("2019-06-30T07:20:59.126Z"),
                "Value": "$__agg0"
            },
            "Count": "$__agg1",
            "_id": NumberInt("0")
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: can the person that downvoted that solution explain why?

Comment: @Thomas most likely due to their opinion that offering a solution using a library is a crime punishable by downvote :p